# Will openssl 1.0.2 from jessie-backports make it to trusty-backports

Tags: 14.04, openssl

Is there any way to know if openssl 1.0.2 now in [jessie-backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/openssl) will make it into trusty-backports?

Comment: I suggest you ask the maintainers at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl. This isn't really a question we can answer.

Comment: That at least points me in the right direction, thank you.